# How to reset the iPad without PC and iTunes

Tags: ipad, unlock

I have an iPad and I forgot the passcode. I can't remember email ID or Apple ID.  Now I only have the iPad and bill. Many stories I've read suggest to reset the iPad and then login.

How do I do that?  I don't need the data so it's ok to wipe it out.

Comment: i don't need old data.

Comment: Open iforgot.apple.com from there you'll be able to recover your password.

Comment: In iforgot.apple.com asking mail ID or apple ID. I forget both. I don't know which mail id i used.

Comment: How can you forget your e-mail address?

Comment: that is two years back, i used more than two email address.now i formatted my iPad and i can't remember my old email address which i given.

Answer (score -1):

The iPad has been unlocked with help of Apple Support. :)

Thanks everyone.

Comment: How did you unlock it? Apple support tells me it's impossible. I just want to reset to factory default.